how to handle multiple response media types inside produces during making a rest template call
I am calling an API using rest template. This API can either return an image byte[] or error object in json
For some reasons I am not using global exception handler. I am handling exception in same endpoint.
That API which I am calling, sends the image based on id. And in case of HTTP NOT FOUND (particular id not found) case it sends error response in json.
On success case I am able to get image. But in case API returns error response in json , I am getting
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class org.json.simple.JSONObject] with preset Content-Type 'null']

below is the API calling code using rest template
@GetMapping(value="api/image/{id}" , produces = { MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Object> api_image_customer(@PathVariable(name = "id")String id){

        String accessToken = getCrmAccessToken();
        
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        headers.add("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);
        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = null;
        HttpEntity formEntity = new HttpEntity(null, headers);
    
        try {
            response = restTemplate.exchange("http://172.18.5.19:8082/api/image/"+id, HttpMethod.GET,
                    formEntity, byte[].class);

            if(response!=null && response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                byte[] imageBytes = response.getBody();
                return new ResponseEntity<>(imageBytes, HttpStatus.OK);
                
            }
            else if(response!=null && !response.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()){

                return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                
            }
            else
            {
                return new ResponseEntity<>("ERROR", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                
            }
        }
        catch(HttpClientErrorException ex) {
            String msg = ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
            System.out.println(msg+" !!!!"); // this is getting printed as json string.
            JSONParser parser =new JSONParser();
            JSONObject obj = null;
            try {
                obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(msg);

            }catch(Exception ex_) {
                ex_.printStackTrace();
                return new ResponseEntity<>("error converting json", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(obj, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            
        }
    }

I was hoping that, multiple MediaType entries inside produces attribute of @GetMapping will handle both types of responses i.e. image as well as json. But this not happening.
Is there a way that I can manage both types of responses here, like dynamically changing content-type of response.

Here is the solution I got from one of the stackoverflow resources : here
So as per the most voted answer, what I did was added a HttpHeader in my catch block:
catch(HttpClientErrorException ex) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);          
    String msg = ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
    System.out.println(msg+" !!!!"); // this is getting printed as json string.
    JSONParser parser =new JSONParser();
    JSONObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = (JSONObject)parser.parse(msg);

    }catch(Exception ex_) {
        ex_.printStackTrace();
        return new ResponseEntity<>("error converting json", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        
    }
    
    return new ResponseEntity<>(obj,  responseHeaders, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);           
}

That's what I needed. Some sort of dynamic approach. Now I will remember.

You can specify the response type using the Accept header
example:
GET /api/urunler HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json, application/xml

But ahmet, I can't find anything like accept in GetMapping signature

I think you can improve the format of your post with markdown.
